# Streamline random-order jQuery functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, random, fade

Venturing into the world of random sorting and am having trouble combining some functions to be as efficient as possible. **Everything works correctly, but I have the feeling I'm going about it in a newbie kind of way** because I built it with two functions I found here on Stack Overflow that I modified then Frankensteined together.

**I'd love your advice for any ways I can streamline the code for efficiency and to knock out redundancy.**

This function takes 10 divs, rearranges them into a random order, then fades that random order into the page one after the other in an additional random order. The effect is neat, see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/danielredwood/MgFj2/

Thanks so much for your help!

__
Initialize function on page

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    shuffle();
});
```

__
Create array for fade order

```
function introfade(x) {
    var o = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        var n = Math.floor(Math.random()*x);
        if ( $.inArray(n, o) > 0 ) {
            --i;
        } else {
            o.push(n);
        }
    }
    return o;
}
```

__Rearrange divs and fade them in

```
function shuffle() {
    var b       = $('.box'),
        arrange = $('<div>'),
        size    = b.size(),
        fade    = introfade(size);

    while (size >= 1) {
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * size),
            temp = b.get(rand);

        arrange.append(temp);
        b = b.not(temp);
        size--;
    }

    $('.main').html(arrange.html());

    $('.box').each(function(i) {
        var c = $(this);
        setTimeout(function() {
            c.fadeTo(500, 1);
        }, fade[i]*150);
    });
}
```

Comment: +1 for using "Frankenstein" as a verb.

Comment: +1 for 'Everything works correctly, but'

Comment: i know it's not related to your problem or solution, but you should rename some of your variables to something meaningful and/or add some comments in the interest of future developers having to maintain/extend this.

Comment: great point, sorry about that. noted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been using the "inside-out" algorithm for this type of thing. Here's my implementation:

```
/** pushRand

    Insert a value into an array at a random index. The element 
    previously at that index will be pushed back onto the end. 

    @see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_.22inside-out.22_algorithm

    @param {Array} array Array to insert into.
    @param {Mixed} value Value to insert.
    @param {Object} rng Optional RNG. Defaults to Math.
    @return {Number} The new length of the array.

*/
function pushRand (array, value, rng) {
    var j = (rng || Math).random() * (array.length + 1) | 0;
    array.push(array[j]);
    array[j] = value;
    return array.length;
}
```

Using this, your code could be simplified a bit:

```
// Create array for fade order

function introfade(x) {
    var o = [];
    while (x--) pushRand(o, x);
    return o;
}

// Rearrange divs and fade them in

function shuffle() {
    var b       = $('.box'),
        main    = $('.main')[0],
        arrange = $('<div>'),
        size    = b.size(),
        fade    = introfade(size),
        boxes   = [], 
        i;

    for (i = size; i--;) pushRand(boxes, b[i]);
    for (i = size; i--;) main.appendChild(boxes[i]);

    b.each(function(i) {
        var c = $(this);
        setTimeout(function() {
            c.fadeTo(500, 1);
        }, fade[i]*150);
    });
}
```

Take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/MgFj2/2/

Comment: Verrrry interesting, love the combined random function approach. And the algorithm is pretty rad.

Comment: It is a very cool, efficient, lightweight little algorithm. Here's an in-place shuffle to complement it ("modern algorithm" implementation) - http://jsfiddle.net/5kHLp/

Answer (score 1):

I see one optimization.  Instead of randomly choosing a number and then checking if it is in `o`, make an array of the possible values (`a`), and then `splice()` one out at random and append it to `o`.  This way always takes `x` steps.  The other way could take more than double that, especially as `o` is almost full you have a high probability of generating a number that is already in `o`, especially as the size of `x` increases.

```
function introfade(x) {
    var o = [];
    var a = [];
    for(var i=0; i<x; i++) {
         a.push(i);           
    }
    for(var i=x; i>0; i--) {
        var n = Math.floor(Math.random()*i);
        o.push(a.splice(n,1)[0]);           
    }

    return o;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8Jy8T/

Another approach would be to step through the array and swap the entry with another random entry:

```
function introfade(x) {
    var o = [];
    for(var i=0; i<x; i++) {
         o.push(i);           
    }
    for(var i=0; i<x; i++) {
        var n = Math.floor(Math.random()*i);
        var tmp = o[n];
        o[n] = o[i];
        o[i] = tmp;      
    }

    return o;
}
```

Comment: To be honest Jeff, both of these obviously work better than what I was doing. Do you have a recommendation? I understand the concept behind 1, but not 2

Comment: 2 is simply going through a list of numbers `o`, and at each one is randomly swapping it with another one.

Comment: Got it. Sorry I accepted GGG's answer instead; appreciated his combination of the random function into both the sorting and fading. Your help was invaluable. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I'll throw another answer on here for fun...  You can do this with a fairly minimal amount of jQuery:

```
// Rearrange divs and fade them in
function shuffle() {
    var num = $('.box').length - 1;
    $('.box').each(function(i) {
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * num);
        $(this).remove().insertAfter($('.box').eq(rand)).delay(i * 50).fadeTo(250, 1);
    });
}

// Initialize function
$(document).ready(function() {
    shuffle();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gvjrr/

That's the whole thing.  This is slightly different, in that it fades the divs in order (but they are shuffled around the page).  If you wanted to continue to fade them in randomly, you would simply shuffle them first without revealing, and then shuffle and reveal:

```
// Rearrange divs and fade them in
function shuffle() {
    var num = $('.box').length-1;

    $('.box').each(function(i) {
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * num);
        $(this).remove().insertAfter($('.box').eq(rand));
    })

    $('.box').each(function(i) {
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * num);
        $(this).remove().insertAfter($('.box').eq(rand)).delay(i * 50).fadeTo(250, 1);
    });
}

// Initialize function
$(document).ready(function() {
    shuffle();

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AapCP/1/

You could probably simplify this further.